# Add custom class according to taxonomy

Tags: 8, views, taxonomy-terms

I have content type car, which has three fields: car model, year model and category (taxonomy term). In taxonomy term, I have three lists: volvo, toyota and BMW.

In the picture below, I have added a custom class called grid-item and besides that I would like to add a category name such as volvo, toyota or BMW. I would able to add category name if replacement patterns has been available :/

[image]

In the source code, you guys can see that I have class grid-item and I want to have a category name accoding to cars next to it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add taxonomy filed in view and Exclude from display this field.[image]

Comment: I have tried many times before asking here, but it does not work. :/

Comment: Hi! Somehow it is working now, so weird. Many thanks :)